# Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Tags: r, dplyr

I am new to R. I am getting the following error while using the code below. Any help would be highly appreciated

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'.
```

Code

```r
tweets <- bind_rows(
    tweets_rr %>% mutate(person = "rayen"),
    tweets_bb %>% mutate(person = "bin")
) %>% mutate(timestamp = ymd_hms(timestamp))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You may want to check out [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). In particular, it will be tough for anyone to help you without some sense of your data. Can you edit your question to include the output of `dput(head(tweets_rr))` and `dput(head(tweets_bb))`?

Comment: You say it's "individual twitter data from 2 accounts"; how did you get the data? Using the [`twitteR`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=twitteR) package? If so, I would guess there is no part of your datasets called `timestamp`, so it's trying to work with the function `timestamp`, resulting in your error. However, if you could edit your question to include the output of `dput(head(tweets_rr))` and `dput(head(tweets_bb))` we could say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to clarify about my dataset; this is individual twitter data from 2 accounts.

Comment: As you are new to Stackoverflow, let me tell you that the question can be edited any number of times. Hence, If you want to include more info about your question as what @duckmayr has commented, please edit instead of answering the question. This would only attract more downvotes and I would advise to delete the answer as well :)